# Java JDBC - PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() always returns 0

Tags: java

I am working with Model-View-Controller.

I have a `Jframe` form where I insert customers data( nit, name, address....), the insertions works (so I am connected with the DB correctly). Then I need to be able to MODIFY some of that fields and save them into the DB. So I select one of the customers from my table (in the Jframe) changing the values (or data) and save it again but when I try to UPDATE my DB my `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` returns `0` (nothing was changed...so no updates in the table of my jframe or the DB).

This is my ODA class (my DB name is datosclientes and the rest are the variables I have there). my class **modelo** only has my variables, methods setter, and getter.

```
public int modificar(modelo m){
        int r = 0;
        String sSQL="UPDATE  datosclientes SET nit=?, nombre=?, direccion=?, telefono=?, fecha=?, tipo=?, comentario=? WHERE id=?";
        try{
            con=conectar.conectar();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sSQL);
            
            ps.setInt(1,m.getId());
            ps.setString(2,m.getNit());
            ps.setString(3,m.getNombre());
            ps.setString(4,m.getDireccion());
            ps.setString(5,m.getTelefono());
            ps.setString(6,m.getFecha());
            ps.setString(7,m.getTipoSer());
            ps.setString(8,m.getComentario());
            r= ps.executeUpdate();
            
            
            if(r==1){
                return 1;
            }else{
               
                return 0;
                
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no se pudo modificar desde DOA" + e, " modeloODA ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }//end catch
        return r;
        
    }
```

in my controller class I have:

```
public void actualizar(){
    
    int id=Integer.parseInt(mTickete.txtId.getText());
    String nit=mTickete.txtNit.getText();
    String nom= mTickete.txtNom.getText();
    String dir=mTickete.txtDir.getText();
    String tel= mTickete.txtTel.getText();
    String fec= mTickete.txtFec.getText();
    String tip= mTickete.cbxTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String com= mTickete.taCom.getSelectedText();
    try{
        Modelo.setId(id);
        Modelo.setNit(nit);
        Modelo.setNombre(nom);
        Modelo.setDireccion(dir);
        Modelo.setTelefono(tel);
        Modelo.setFecha(fec);
        Modelo.setTipoSer(tip);
        Modelo.setComentario(com);
        int r=dao.modificar(Modelo);
        if(r==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cTickete, "Usuarios actualizado correctamente");
           
    }
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no se pudo modificar desde controlador" + e, " modeloODA ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your id is the 8th parameter, but you set it using `ps.setInt(1,m.getId());`.

Answer (score 3):

The last parameter passed to the ps must be the id... at the moment it is the Comentario. Replace the code

```
        ps.setInt(1,m.getId());
        ps.setString(2,m.getNit());
        ps.setString(3,m.getNombre());
        ps.setString(4,m.getDireccion());
        ps.setString(5,m.getTelefono());
        ps.setString(6,m.getFecha());
        ps.setString(7,m.getTipoSer());
        ps.setString(8,m.getComentario());
```

with

```
        ps.setString(1,m.getNit());
        ps.setString(2,m.getNombre());
        ps.setString(3,m.getDireccion());
        ps.setString(4,m.getTelefono());
        ps.setString(5,m.getFecha());
        ps.setString(6,m.getTipoSer());
        ps.setString(7,m.getComentario());
        ps.setInt(8,m.getId());   // Moved at the end
```